# mysql foreign key error in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created two migrations:

**Migration 1**

```
    Schema::create('responders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->double('latitude', 10, 6);
        $table->double('longitude', 10, 6);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Migration 2**

```
    Schema::create('devices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->string('device_id');
        $table->string('device_token');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('user_id')
            ->on('responders')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

When I start migration the error message is being thrown:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: alter table `devices` add constraint devices_user_id_foreign
>   foreign key (`user_id`) references `responders` (`user_id`) on delete
>   cascade)
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

I specifically took care that the data types are the same. In this case both are of type `string`. Why does the foreign key can't be established?

Comment: The foreign key can't be defined because there is no unique index on the `user_id` column of the `responders` table. If you want to define a foreign key, add an index on the referenced column(s).

Comment: are you sure $table->string('user_id'); should be string not integer?

Comment: there is some thing also wrong with your logic I think, let me understand so I can help you, responders will have many devices is that correct? and responders belong to a user? is that correct

Comment: show the schema as output from the server not hand typed

Answer (score 1):

> A **foreign key** is a column (or columns) that references a column (most
>   often the primary **key**) of another table. The purpose of the **foreign**
>   **key** is to ensure referential integrity of the data. In other words,
>   only values that are supposed to appear in the database are permitted.

Here **`user_id`** in **`responders`** table isn't a **`key`** that's why it's showing this error.